# Please help smoothing animation using accelerometer javascript reading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, accelerometer

I've created an algorithm to create a parallax background effect. Which uses mobile's accelerometer reading to animate background image on phones.

However the parallax works but the animation is not smooth it shakes a lot. You can find complete code on my git repository: [Acclerometer Parallax On GitHub](https://github.com/TheAkashRajput/Accelerometer-Parallax/)

Please consider helping me here. It's a really cool plugin but needs contribution. I've spent hours optimizing the code. But still haven't got the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally managed to smooth the data. The problem is that I was using gyroscope data instead of accelerometer data.